# Making a field Unique after crossing 5000 items in a SPList in SPO site

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, splist, unique

Am having a SPO site,with SPList with 5300 items and one of the fields must be a  unique field. But, because since its crossed 5000 items, i am unable to make the  field as unique field. This field is a `single line of text`

when i tried to make the field as `Enforce Unique values` am getting the below error:

`the attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.`

How to perform this  uniqueness for this  field

Answer (score 0):

The typical, unfortunate guidance has been to get rid of enough items to get the list below 5000, make your change, and add them back in.

Comment: after deletion of those items , how can i get back ? is it reside in recyclebin and can i take it back from recycle bin , just by restore items?

Comment: The recycyle bin might work, in theory, but I certainly wouldn't recommend it as a strategy. Instead, perhaps save the list as a template (from list settings), then copy over a few hundred records. After making the field unique, you could then copy them back. Of course, this will mess with the modified date and modified by fields. If this is a problem, tools like sharegate can move list items around while preserving these fields.

Comment: Is there any easy way for "then copy over a few hundred records."... in my case, each and every listitem has attachments. So, will these attachments also move to a 2nd splist (copied list)

Comment: Attachments does complicate it a bit. Go to site settings --> content and structure, click on your list on the left side.  In the right panel, select some list items and actions--> move. Move them to a different list (that you created via a list template, so that it has all the same fields, etc.) Clearly, test this on a different, non-production list first.